# Distribution of model summs of squares: $Y^T P_x Y$ and Residual SS $Y^T(I-P_x)Y$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, variance, chi-squared

$\hat\beta$ is the least square estimator and $P_x=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

> Why does $Y^T P_x  Y \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2(p,\sigma^{-2}\beta^TX^TP_xX\beta)$ and RSS $\sim\sigma^2\chi^2(p,\sigma^{-2}\beta^TX^TX\beta)$

The assumption is that $Y$ is normally distributed. If I understand correctly, $Y\sim N(X\beta,I\sigma^2)$

I thought $\frac{Y^TY}{\sigma^2}$ is disributed with $\chi^2$

In particular, $(Y-X\beta)\sigma I^{-1}\sim N(0,1)$ and hence $\sigma I^{-1}(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)\sigma I\sim \chi^2$

I'm not sure about degrees of freedom.

$Y^TP_xY=Y^TY-e^Te$ where $e=Y-X\hat\beta$, the error vector. I also know that $\hat\beta \sim N(\beta, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write $(Y-X\beta)\sigma I^{-1}\sim N(0,1)$ you're confusing matrices with scalars.  The notation $N(0,1)$ is that of a scalar-valued random variable.

Where you write $N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)$ (I've always seen the scalar factor written to the left of the matrix) the vector $X\beta$ is $n\times 1$ and the matrix $\sigma^2 I$ is $n\times n$.  Generally if you have
$$
W\sim N(a,M)
$$
where $a$ is $n\times 1$ and $M$ is $n\times n$, then for a $k\times n$ matrix $A$ you have
$$
AW \sim N(Aa, AMA^T)
$$
and so $AMA^T$ is a $k\times k$ matrix.  That's the matrix counterpart of a familiar identity for variance of a constant multiple of a random vector.  If yo want to multiply be something to get unit variance, you rely on a result from linear algebra that says a positive-definite symmetric matrix $M$ with real entries has a postive-definite symmetric square root, whose inverse let us call $M^{-1/2}$.  So if
$$
W\sim N(0, M)
$$
then
$$
M^{-1/2} W \sim N(0, I)
$$
and there you have unit variance, the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  Also, note that $I^{-1} = I$ and $(\sigma I)^{-1} = \sigma^{-1} I$, not $\sigma I^{-1}$.

You should have $P_X$, not $P_x$, i.e. $P_X = X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $X$.

Since $(I-P_X)X=0$ and $Y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)$, you have
$$
(I-P_X)Y \sim N(0, \sigma^2 (I-P_X)(I-P_X)^T).
$$
an easy bit of algebra tells you that $(I-P_X)(I-P_X)^T = I-P_X$.  (Use the fact that $PX^2=P_X^T = P_X$.) So you have
$$
(I-P_X)Y \sim N(0, \sigma^2 (I-P_X))
$$
with (note well) expected value $0$.

The matrix $(I-P_X)$ is a projection onto a space of dimension $n-k$ where $k$ is the number of columns of $X$, and the expected value of $Y$, which is $X\beta$, projects to the zero vector. So let us choose an orthonormal basis of the column space of $X$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$.  In that basis the matrix of $I-P_X$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & 1 \\ & & & & 0 \\ & & & & & \ddots \\ & & & & & & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $n-k$ ones and $k$ zeros.  Transforming $N(0,\sigma^2(I-P_X))$ into that basis, you see that the square of the norm of a vector with that distribution is distributed as $\sigma^2 \chi^2_{n-k}$.

That is the vector, not of the **errors**, but of the **residuals**. The difference is this:
\begin{align}
\text{vector of errors} & = Y-X\beta, \\[10pt]
\text{vector of residuals} & = Y - X\widehat\beta.
\end{align}

Comment: I've posted more detailed accounts of this same point in other answers. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I learned a lot from these little remarks, however I have one more quesion: If I understand the RSS is given by $Y^T(I-P_X)^T(I-P_X)Y=Y^T(I-P_X)Y$. Now $(I-P_X)$ is a projection of $Y$ onto the orthogonal $\perp C(X)$ (othrogonal column space). Since $X$ has rank $k$ and $y=n\times 1$ we have that $\perp C(X)$ is $n-k$ dimensional. Then you square the $(I-P_X)Y\sim N(0,...)$, but I fail to see how $\chi^2(k,\sigma^{-2}\beta^TX^TX\beta)$ would come in

Comment: @GRS : You have $\widehat\beta\sim N(\beta, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$.  That's a $k$-dimensional normal distribution with a non-zero expected value.  If the expected value were $0$ and if the variance were $I_k$ (the $k\times k$ identity matrix) then its norm would be distributed as $\chi^2_k$.  The fact that the expected value is not $0$ means you get a non-central distribution. But the situation is complicated by the nature of the variance --- I'd have to work through the details.  If you have a null hypothesis that $\beta=0$, then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$then you would have an F-test whose denominator is the residual sum of squares and whose numerator would be just the chi-square statistic you're talking about in your comment.  The reason for concern with the non-central case, involving a false null hypothesis, would be to find the power of the test as a function of $\beta$. $\qquad$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. It's just because I was simply given the distributions in this book, I wanted to know the nature of it

Comment: Here's something related:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928946/prove-that-the-the-variance-estimator-widehat-sigma2-mse-n-2-is-biased-i/929010#929010